# How can I ensure that a cloned HTML node has a specific property (when Unit Testing)?

Tags: html, typescript, unit-testing, clone

I am creating an HTML clone using

`var clone = document.getElementById('tempID').cloneNode(true);`

Then, I want to edit the id, using `clone['id'] = newUniqueID;` (I'm creating multiple clones, so each one will have its own id)

This works when running the app, but the Unit Tests won't allow it, it is giving this error:

`Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Node'`

I tried putting these two lines inside this if statement, to guarantee the element exists, but I'm still getting the same error in the Unit Test:

```
if(document.getElementById('tempID') !== null){
  var clone = document.getElementById('tempID').cloneNode(true);
  clone['id'] = newUniqueID;
}
```

In this scenario, the id is guaranteed to exist when using `clone['id']`, so why does the Unit Test claim it doesn't exist? What is the workaround for this?

Note: The entire test suite fails to run due to this error, so it isn't a problem with a specific test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, I had to change from:

`var clone = document.getElementById('tempID').cloneNode(true);`

to this:

`var clone: any = document.getElementById('tempID')!.cloneNode(true);`

I'm not sure why declaring it as "any" has an impact on the id, but I had to add the `!` operator to tell the compiler that the element is not null. The if statement in my post is not necessary.